# Finding the diagonals of any random point in a square 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, matrix, intellij-idea

I have to write the code that sets an 8x8 matrix, a chessboard, and then asks the user what row and what column they want to place the queen on. I then have to put a * on each square to which the queen can move. Putting a * on the row and column the queen could move to wasn't difficult but I'm having trouble correctly labeling the diagonals to on which the queen can move. This is the code I have written so far to try and locate the diagonal:

```
    char[][] chessboard = new char[8][8];
            System.out.print("What row do you want to place the queen on? ");
            int row = console.nextInt();
            System.out.print("What column do you want to place the queen on? ");
            int column = console.nextInt();

            char queen = 'Q';
            chessboard[row - 1][column - 1] = queen;

            // column and rows
            for (int i = 0; i < chessboard.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < chessboard[0].length; j++) {
                    if ((i == 2 || j == 6) && chessboard[i][j] != queen) {
                        chessboard[i][j] = '*';
                    }
                }
            }

            if ((row - 1) != 0) {
                // left diagonal
                for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                    for (int j = (column - 1 - (row - 1)); ((column - 1) - (row - 1)) <= j && j < column; j++) {
                        if (chessboard[i][j] != queen) {
                            chessboard[i][j] = '*';
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int i = (row - 1) + (8 - (column)); i >= row - 1; i--) {
                    for (int j = 7; j >= (column - 1); j--) {
                        if (chessboard[i][j] != queen) {
                            chessboard[i][j] = '*';
                        }
                    }
                }

                // right diagonal
                for (int i = 7; i >= row - 1; i--) {
                    for (int j = (column - 1 - (row - 1)); 0 <= j && j < column; j--) {
                        if (chessboard[i][j] != queen) {
                            chessboard[i][j] = '*';
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
 for (int i = 0; i < chessboard.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < chessboard[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(chessboard[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

When I put in experimental values, for example row 3 and column 7, I get a really messy output. For the numbers above, I get:

```
[][][][] * * * [] 
[][][][] * * * [] 
* * * *  * * Q  * 
* * * * * [] *  * 
* * * * * [] * [] 
* * * * * [] * [] 
* * * * * [] * [] 
* * * * * [] * []
```

Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong?
* This is a homework question so code only in the answers, please. Thanks!

Comment: What do the square brackets represent in your output?

Comment: @ManoDestra They're supposed to be empty matrix slots. That's how they appear in Intellij-idea on my computer.

Comment: If it were me, I'd simply loop through each square of the chessboard and test the validity of each square as being one that the queen can move to, of the three possible rules, namely (square.x == queen.x || square.y == queen.y || square.x - queen.x == square.y - queen.y). If your square matches any of the above rules, then it's a valid square to move to, otherwise it's not. Omitting the square that the queen currently resides on, of course (square.x != queen.x && square.y != queen.y). Make sense?

Comment: @ManoDestra I hadn't thought of it that way, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were me, I'd simply loop through each square of the chessboard and test the validity of each square as being one that the queen can move to, of the three possible rules, namely

```
square.x == queen.x ||
square.y == queen.y ||
|square.x - queen.x| == |square.y - queen.y|
```

If your square matches any of the above rules, then it's a valid square to move to, otherwise it's not. Omitting the square that the queen currently resides on, of course

```
square.x != queen.x && square.y != queen.y
```

Pseudocode:

```
for (int i = 0; i < chessboard.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < chessboard[0].length; j++) {
        // You could encapsulate these lines in a isValidSquareForQueenMove(x, y) method.
        boolean isSquareValid = false;
        isSquareValid = isSquareValid || x == queen.x;
        isSquareValid = isSquareValid || y == queen.y;
        isSquareValid = isSquareValid || Math.abs(queen.x - x) == Math.abs(queen.y - y);
        isSquareValid = isSquareValid && x != queen.x && y != queen.y;

        // Do stuff here.
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to add that the queen.x - x == queen.y - y finds one diagonal but queen.x - x == y - queen.y finds the second so that code should be added.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. You could just check the modulus value of the difference though. I'll update the answer to use Math.abs so that one piece of logic manages both diagonals.